# What are the Perl equivalents of return and continue keywords in C?

Tags: perl

I am getting this error when I use this code

```
sub search {
    my ($a, @a_list) = @_;
    foreach (@a_list) {
        if($_ == $a) return TRUE;
        # continue;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

> syntax error at code.pl line 26, near ") return"

- What is the right way to `return TRUE`?
- Also, what is the right way to `continue`?

I know I should be thinking more in Perl terms than trying to convert C code to Perl this way.

Comment: Your search function can be collapsed into a call to `any`: `use List::MoreUtils 'any'; my $matched = any { $_ eq $a } @a_list;`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### Equivalents of return, continue, break

- `return` is the equivalent of return.
- `next` is the equivalent of continue.
- `last` is the equivalent of break.

#### 'if' statements are followed by blocks

Your problem is that an `if` statement is always followed by a block inside braces.

```
if ($_ == $a) { return TRUE; }
elsif (...)   { ... }
else          { ... }
```

For all it sometimes seems a bit verbose, I agree with [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) that this is something that Perl got right.  For an interesting alternative take, see the [Go](http://golang.org/) programming language, which treats the parentheses as unnecessary and mandates the braces.

#### 'if' can be used as a qualifier

Or you can use the `if` as a statement modifier:

```
return TRUE if $_ == $a;
```

Note that in this case, you don't have to use parentheses around the conditional expression, though there'd be no harm in adding them.

#### Using 'unless'

You can also use `unless` instead of `if` to invert the condition:

```
return TRUE unless $_ != $a;
```

(And, as [Phillip Potter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276952/philip-potter) pointed out, mixing `unless` with a negated condition makes comprehension harder; the example is directly doing the same as the question, but is better written as an `if` with equality.)

#### Using 'next' and 'last'

You can use `next` and `last` similarly:

```
sub search {
    my ($a, @a_list) = @_;
    foreach (@a_list) {
        return TRUE if $_ == $a;
        last if $_ > $a;
        next if $ptom != LAST_QUARTER;
        ...
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

<s>Note the fixup in the `foreach` loop.</s> (*Question amended to include the fixup.*)  Make sure you always have '`use strict;`' and '`use warnings;`' at the top of your script.  Experts always use them to make sure they haven't made mistakes.  Beginners should use them for exactly the same reason.

#### TRUE and FALSE

Also, as pointed out first in other answers, Perl does not have pre-defined constants TRUE and FALSE, any more than C or C++ do (C++ has a built-in `true` and `false`; C99 has `true` and `false` conditionally available if you `#include <stdbool.h>`).  You can provide the definitions for Perl as:

```
use constant TRUE => 1;
use constant FALSE => 0;
```

Be wary, though.  Some things will be 'true' even when not equal to TRUE; other things will be 'false' even when not equal to FALSE.

---

#### Discussion about use of '$a' and '$b'

The comments contain a discussion about not using `$a` and `$b` as variables.  In sequence, the relevant comments were:

- Please avoid using $a unless it's in a sort block. – [Zaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133939/zaid)
- @Zaid: Good point that $a and $b are special in the context of a sort block. I'm not sure whether there are edicts that they should never be used otherwise - it would be atrocious to use them when there is also a sort block lurking around, but in the absence of sort blocks, I don't see any reason to treat $a and different than $z. – Jonathan Leffler
- $a and $b are globals, and as such behave different than lexicals. – [phaylon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144633/phaylon)
- @phaylon: well, strictly they are 'package globals' (see Perl [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)). Yes, when you are sorting, they are different from lexicals (my) variables. When you aren't doing sorting, then they can be treated as lexicals if you declare them explicitly. – Jonathan Leffler
- @Jonathan Leffler, they are also exempt from use strict qw(vars); so you might not notice that you are trampling on them from another scope. – [Ven'Tatsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199914/ventatsu)

Pointing out the obvious: I only used `$a` because the question did - and rather than inundate the original poster with lots of details, I kept mostly to the main points.  For example, the discussion of `last` and `next` does not mention loop labels.

That said, the advice "avoid using `$a` and `$b` as variables" is sound; they are special names for the reasons pointed out, and using them leaves open the possibility of mistakes that may or may not be be detectable.

Comment: ...but don't ever use `unless` with a negative condition such as one which uses `!` or `!=`. It's the code equivalent of a double negative, and it just confuses people.

Comment: Please avoid using `$a` unless it's in a `sort` block.

Comment: @Philip: Yes - agreed in general; I was just keeping the condition consistent, which maybe wasn't the best choice.  Certainly, in the context, there is no call for 'unless'.

Comment: @Zaid: Good point that $a and $b are special in the context of a sort block.  I'm not sure whether there are edicts that they should never be used otherwise - it would be atrocious to use them when there is also a sort block lurking around, but in the absence of sort blocks, I don't see any reason to treat $a and different than $z.

Comment: "next" and "last" are definitely not the same thing.

Comment: always requiring {} for if statements is one of the things Perl got right

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: $a and $b are globals, and as such behave different than lexicals.

Comment: @phaylon: well, strictly they are 'package globals' (see [Perl sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)).  Yes, when you are sorting, they are different from lexicals (`my`) variables.  When you aren't doing sorting, then they can be treated as lexicals if you declare them explicitly.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, they are also exempt from `use strict qw(vars);` so you might not notice that you are trampling on them from another scope.

Comment: else after return? bad practice.

Answer (score 7):

Your question has been (very!) comprehensively answered by Jonathan, but I wanted to point out a few other, more perlish ways to replace your "search" function.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @a_list = (1, 2, 3);
my $a = 2;

# If you're using 5.10 or higher, you can use smart matching.
# Note that this is only equivalent if $a is a number.
# That is, "2.0" ~~ ["1", "2", "3"] is false.
say $a ~~ @a_list;

# Need to install List::MoreUtils, not a standard module
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
say any { $a == $_ } @a_list;

# List::Util is a core module
use List::Util qw(first);
say defined first { $a == $_ } @a_list;

# No modules used, but less efficient
say grep { $a == $_ } @a_list > 0;
```

For more info, see the documentation for [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail), [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~vparseval/List-MoreUtils-0.22/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm),
[List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) and [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

Answer (score 4):

Perl does not have built in constants for true and false.  The canonical value for true is `1` and for false is `()` (which is an empty list in list context, and undef in scalar context).

A more idomatic way to write your code would be:

```
sub search {
    my $key = shift;
    foreach (@_) {
        return 1 if $_ == $key;
    }
    return ();
}
```