# tons of "Use of uninitialized value within %genetic_code in substitution iterator"

Tags: perl

I want to translate a sequence of DNA or RNA to protein, but after run it, I have tons of "Use of uninitialized value within %genetic_code in substitution iterator at translateRNAToProtein.pl line 95,  line 1." warning. I double checked the translation table and no error there. My code is following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

translation (my $sequence);
my %genetic_code = (
    UCA => 'S',
UCC => 'S',
UCG => 'S',
UCU => 'S',
UUC => 'F',
UUU => 'F',
UUA => 'L',
UUG => 'L',
UAC => 'Y',
UAU => 'Y',
UAA => '_',
UAG => '_',
UGC => 'C',
UGU => 'C',
UGA => '_',
UGG => 'W',
CUA => 'L',
CUC => 'L',
CUG => 'L',
CUU => 'L',
CCA => 'P',
CCC => 'P',
CCG => 'P',
CCU => 'P',
CAC => 'H',
CAU => 'H',
CAA => 'Q',
CAG => 'Q',
CGA => 'R',
CGC => 'R',
CGG => 'R',
CGU => 'R',
AUA => 'I',
AUC => 'I',
AUU => 'I',
AUG => 'M',
ACA => 'U',
ACC => 'U',
ACG => 'U',
ACU => 'U',
AAC => 'N',
AAU => 'N',
AAA => 'K',
AAG => 'K',
AGC => 'S',
AGU => 'S',
AGA => 'R',
AGG => 'R',
GUA => 'V',
GUC => 'V',
GUG => 'V',
GUU => 'V',
GCA => 'A',
GCC => 'A',
GCG => 'A',
GCU => 'A',
GAC => 'D',
GAU => 'D',
GAA => 'E',
GAG => 'E',
GGA => 'G',
GGC => 'G',
GGG => 'G',
GGU => 'G',
);

sub translation {
    say "enter a RNA or DNA sequence: ";
    my $sequence = <STDIN>;
    chomp $sequence;
    $sequence = uc ($sequence);
    if ($sequence =~ /T/){
        $sequence =~ tr/ATGC/UACG/;
    }

    say "\nThe result of translation is:\n\n";  
    foreach ($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) {
        my $main_seq = substr($sequence, $a);
        if ($main_seq =~ /(AUG(...)*(UAG|UGA|UAA))/){
            $main_seq = $1;

            $main_seq =~ s/(...)/$genetic_code{$1}/g;       #Here is the warning place
            say "$main_seq\n";
        }

        else {
            say "No start or stop codon!"
        }

    }
}
```

Other parts work fine. For example, when I enter a 669 bp DNA:

```
TACATCCACCACACCATTTCCGCCAATGAAATTTGCATGCAAATCAATCCAGGTTCTTCAAACTGTATGCCCAGTCAACCCAGTCATGCAACACTGACCATTGAATCCATCAATTCAGAAACAGACGAAAGGACCAAGACACGGTTTCGCTGCAGGTTTGAAGGGTGCAAACGAACTTACAGCTCTGCTGGAAACTTGAAAGCACACACTAAAAGTCACACAGGGGAGTATACATTTAAATGTACTGAAGAAGAATGTGGGAAGGCATTTCTCAACTCCCACAGCCTAAAGATTCATGTCAGAGTACACACCAAAGATCGTCCCTATGGCTGTGACATTGGGGGATGTGACAAGAACTTCAACACACTCTACCGATTGAAAGCTCATCAGAGGGTACACAACGGCACCACCTTTAAATGTGAACAATCTGGATGTGTGAAATTCTTCACCACCCTCAGTGACTTACGGAAACACGAACGTGTCCATTCGGGAGACCGGCCATTCAAATGCGAGCACGAAGATTGCAACAAGTCATTTCGCAATAGCCATCATCTGAAATCGCACATGTTATCTCATACGGGTGAACGACCCTACACATGCAGTGATTCTGCATGTGGACGAACCTTCGCCAAGCGTAATTCGTGGAAGTTGCATCTATTGAAGCATGAA
```

it can correctly recognize it, convert it to RNA and find the sequences from start codon to stop codon:

```
AUGUAGGUGGUGUGGUAAAGGCGGUUACUUUAAACGUACGUUUAGUUAGGUCCAAGAAGUUUGACAUACGGGUCAGUUGGGUCAGUACGUUGUGACUGGUAACUUAGGUAGUUAAGUCUUUGUCUGCUUUCCUGGUUCUGUGCCAAAGCGACGUCCAAACUUCCCACGUUUGCUUGAAUGUCGAGACGACCUUUGAACUUUCGUGUGUGAUUUUCAGUGUGUCCCCUCAUAUGUAAAUUUACAUGACUUCUUCUUACACCCUUCCGUAAAGAGUUGAGGGUGUCGGAUUUCUAAGUACAGUCUCAUGUGUGGUUUCUAGCAGGGAUACCGACACUGUAA
AUGUCGAGACGACCUUUGAACUUUCGUGUGUGAUUUUCAGUGUGUCCCCUCAUAUGUAAAUUUACAUGACUUCUUCUUACACCCUUCCGUAAAGAGUUGAGGGUGUCGGAUUUCUAAGUACAGUCUCAUGUGUGGUUUCUAGCAGGGAUACCGACACUGUAA
AUGUCGAGACGACCUUUGAACUUUCGUGUGUGAUUUUCAGUGUGUCCCCUCAUAUGUAAAUUUACAUGACUUCUUCUUACACCCUUCCGUAAAGAGUUGAGGGUGUCGGAUUUCUAAGUACAGUCUCAUGUGUGGUUUCUAGCAGGGAUACCGACACUGUAA
```

However, when I try to use a short sequence "uacauguauuaacag" to test this code,
it returns "UACAUGUAUUAACAG", "AUGUAUUAA"(which I add extra code to print out and get what I expected) and three warnings shown above. So clearly it's not an error from translation table. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Ask] and [About] pages. Show some of the relevant translation table — you say there's no error, but Perl appears to disagree with you. Have you printed `$main_seq`? Have you printed the value of `$1` in the substitution? Do you need an `e` modifier in the replacement string? Have you tried showing us some minimal data (5 translation entries; 5 lines of data that should translate OK but don't, and preferably 1-5 lines that do translate OK, if you have any)?  Read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), please, and add the missing information.

Comment: Have added additional information

Comment: You haven't read what I said carefully.  Minimal doesn't mean "everything you currently have".  It means 5 lines of translations, not 40.  It means supply an input that, given your script as amended, produces the warning messages you're suffering from.  And it means show the output you get and the output you expect from the data that you provided.  And, unless there's a very good reason for it to be otherwise, the data should be 80-character lines or so, not massive long strings.  What you show needn't be biologically accurate; it merely needs to reproduce the warning messages.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You have strict turned on but you never declared your loop variable $a (which btw is reserved for sort blocks). Please show your complete code.

Comment: Because `$a` is used by `sort`, it doesn't have to be declared.  It's a gotcha.  See [What are the Perl equivalents of `return` and `continue` keywords in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575979/what-are-the-perl-equivalents-of-return-and-continue-keywords-in-c/3576015#3576015) which contains a discussion of the issues around `$a` and `$b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you invoke `translation()` before you've defined `%genetic_code`.  Simply moving `translation(my $sequence);` to after the definition of `%genetic_code` (and `&translation`) resolves the problem.  Of course, you should remove the unused and uninitialized parameter too.  Hence, from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my %genetic_code = (
    UCA => 'S', UCC => 'S', UCG => 'S', UCU => 'S',
    UUC => 'F', UUU => 'F', UUA => 'L', UUG => 'L',
    UAC => 'Y', UAU => 'Y', UAA => '_', UAG => '_',
    UGC => 'C', UGU => 'C', UGA => '_', UGG => 'W',
    CUA => 'L', CUC => 'L', CUG => 'L', CUU => 'L',
    CCA => 'P', CCC => 'P', CCG => 'P', CCU => 'P',
    CAC => 'H', CAU => 'H', CAA => 'Q', CAG => 'Q',
    CGA => 'R', CGC => 'R', CGG => 'R', CGU => 'R',
    AUA => 'I', AUC => 'I', AUU => 'I', AUG => 'M',
    ACA => 'U', ACC => 'U', ACG => 'U', ACU => 'U',
    AAC => 'N', AAU => 'N', AAA => 'K', AAG => 'K',
    AGC => 'S', AGU => 'S', AGA => 'R', AGG => 'R',
    GUA => 'V', GUC => 'V', GUG => 'V', GUU => 'V',
    GCA => 'A', GCC => 'A', GCG => 'A', GCU => 'A',
    GAC => 'D', GAU => 'D', GAA => 'E', GAG => 'E',
    GGA => 'G', GGC => 'G', GGG => 'G', GGU => 'G',
);

sub translation {
    say "enter a RNA or DNA sequence: ";
    my $sequence = <STDIN>;
    chomp $sequence;
    $sequence = uc ($sequence);
    if ($sequence =~ /T/){
        $sequence =~ tr/ATGC/UACG/;
    }

    say "\nThe result of translation is:\n\n";  
    foreach ($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) {
        my $main_seq = substr($sequence, $a);
        if ($main_seq =~ /(AUG(...)*(UAG|UGA|UAA))/){
            $main_seq = $1;
            $main_seq =~ s/(...)/$genetic_code{$1}/g;
            say "$main_seq\n";
        }
        else {
            say "No start or stop codon!"
        }
    }
}

translation();
```

And given the first line of data as input, the output is:

```
enter a RNA or DNA sequence: 

The result of translation is:


M_VVW_RRLL_UYV_LGPRSLUYGSVGSVRCDW_LR_LSLCLLSWFCAKAUSKLPUFA_MSRRPLNFRV_FSVCPLICKFU_LLLUPFRKELRVSDF_VQSHVWFLAGIPUL_

MSRRPLNFRV_FSVCPLICKFU_LLLUPFRKELRVSDF_VQSHVWFLAGIPUL_

MSRRPLNFRV_FSVCPLICKFU_LLLUPFRKELRVSDF_VQSHVWFLAGIPUL_
```

With absolutely no warnings about uninitialized values.

Comment: Yes indeed, this is the problem! Thank you so much! But I still have a problem: the translation supposes to stop at the first UAG or UGA or UAA codon, but it seems to stop at the first UAA codon only (which means there shouldn't have "_" symbol in protein). How can I modify the code "$main_seq =~ /(AUG(...)*(UAG|UGA|UAA))/"?

Comment: That, my friend, is a different question.  Please ask it as a new question.  I don't understand the logic of what you're up to in the translation function.  You seem to be clobbering `$main_seq` in the `if` statement with `$main_seq = $1;` - after finding an AUG somewhere followed by zero or more triples (greedy — are you sure you wanted greedy matching?) and terminated by UAG, UGA or UAA.  So, you chuck away loads of material, then map the first triplet with the genetic code, and report what you've got, then go back to your 1..3 (or 0..2) loop and have another go.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much for the help!