# how to assign a value to a hash in perl

Tags: perl

This is a part of work. In this part, I'm trying to write a program to create a hash. The keys are accession numbers in a file, the values are the entire lines. However, the program gives me a warning. The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#psuedocode:
#open file1, store uniport accesion as key and the line as value
#open file2, store uniport accesion as key and the line as value which lines contain "IDA"
#compare keys in two hashes, find out matched keys
#print out lines from file2 that match

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $infile1 = "geneIDs3_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt";
my $inFH1;
open ($inFH1, "<", $infile1) or die join (" ", "Can't open", $infile1, "for reading:", $!);
my @array1 = <$inFH1>;
close $inFH1;
shift @array1;
my %geneID1;
for ($a = 0; $a < scalar @array1; $a++){
    chomp $array1[$a];
    $array1[$a] =~ /.*?\t(.*?)\t.*/;
    $geneID1{$1} = $array1[$a];
    #say ("$1", '->', "$geneID1{$array1[$a]}");    #test if the hash has been successfully created, however it doesn't
    #say $array1[$a];              #test if the program can recognize the elements, it does
}
```

the file `geneIDs3_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt` contains 1,000 lines so the warnings are numerous. The first two lines are:

```
From    To  Species Gene Name
PNMA3   Q9H0A4  Homo sapiens    paraneoplastic antigen MA3
```

The warning likes this:

```
Use of uninitialized value within %geneID1 in string at match_for_part_III_10.pl line 24.
Q9H0A4->
```

I found the solution: use `while` loop instead. Not only it works, but also it is more elegant. The new code is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

#psuedocode:
#open file1, store uniport accesion as key and the line as value
#open file2, store uniport accesion as key and the line as value which lines contain "IDA"
#compare keys in two hashes, find out matched keys
#print out lines from file2 that match

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $infile1 = "geneIDs3_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt";
my $inFH1;
open ($inFH1, "<", $infile1) or die join (" ", "Can't open", $infile1, "for reading:", $!);
my %geneID1;

while (<$inFH1>){
    $_ =~ /.*?\t(.*?)\t.*/;
    $geneID1{$1} = $_;
    say ("$1", '->', "$geneID1{$1}");
}
close $inFH1;
```

Thank you all for your incredible help!

Comment: Warnings = you didn't handle some case, probably missing data.  Why don't you print them out and take a look.

Comment: @zdim Other parts work just fine. I don't need to declare `$a`, please read the comment from my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739301/tons-of-use-of-uninitialized-value-within-genetic-code-in-substitution-iterato

Comment: @zdim, `$a` is always declared.

Comment: @Wenjia Zhai, You know `$a` is special, yet you use it anyway? Bad you!

Comment: @ikegami  yeah ... didn't think it works always ... _why_ would one want to go for that ... sigh

Comment: @Wenjia Zhai, I'm not sure what the point of that comment was.

Comment: @Wenjia Zhai, You assign to `$geneID1{$1}`, but you check the contents  of `$geneID1{$array1[$a]}`...

Comment: @WenjiaZhai You just changed `$geneID1{$1}` into `$geneID1{$array1[$a]}`. You shouldn't do that, since it's a totally different situation now. This might obscur the warnings. And what about the two answers you got, don't you want to comment on them?

Comment: @yacc I tried both ways and the warning insists. I need to understand those answers before I can comment

Comment: @WenjiaZhai And in a prior version $a started from 1. It doesn't help people to understand your code if you change it while they're at it. I suggest to print $a so you get a hint on which line this occurs, and the content of that line maybe would be good to know, too.

Comment: I would guess that your data doesn't have tab characters, but (4 or 8) spaces, or perhaps multiple tabs where you expect one.  This is very common. Try with `\s+` instead of `\t` (in both places!).  I edited my answer with a comment on this.

Comment: @zdim This kind of file is standardized, the empty space should be tabs.

Comment: Re "*I found the solution: use while loop instead*", No, that did nothing to solve the problem, and *you* aren't the one that "found" it. As mentioned above, the problem is that you were using the wrong key. (You assigned to `$geneID1{$1}`, but you check the contents of `$geneID1{$array1[$a]}`)

Comment: @ikegami I can't agree. Before I posted, I used same variables, buy there was still a warning.

Comment: @WenjiaZhai I'd also be interested in the root cause of the warning, but the code has changed so much that's impossible to tell now. However...

Comment: @yacc, As I mentioned twice already, the warning was caused by Wenjia Zhai printing `$geneID1{"PNMA3\tQ9H0A4\tHomo sapiens\tparaneoplastic antigen MA3"}` instead of `$geneID1{"Q9H0A4"}` (the element they just set) because of a typo.

Comment: Ok I got it now. That's a good example why question authors shouldn't *improve* their code samples. @ikegami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

<>; # Skip header.

my %geneID1;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split /\t/;
   my $id = $fields[1];
   $geneID1{$id} = $_;
}

say "$_ => $geneID1{$_}" for sort keys %geneID1;
```

(Pass `geneIDs3_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt` as an argument.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. After I tried while loop, it does work. I've put the new code in my original post

Comment: It's unfortunate that re-added the mistakes I removed?!? `$1` is garbage unless you make sure your match succeeded, and your regex is a poorly readable and slow way of splitting on tabs. It's also unfortunate that you reverted to an inflexible interface instead of accepting the file name as an argument.

Comment: @yacc, You are wrong. A failed match does not change `$1` whatsoever, as you can see by running the following: `perl -Mfeature=say -e'for (qw( abc def )) { /(b)/; say $1 // "[undef]"; }'` /// Furthermore, failed match setting `$1` to `undef` would actually have been a good thing, and my program does exactly the same thing (sets `$id` to `undef` if there's no tabs).

Comment: You're right, I got that wrong. Maybe I got this from an earlier Perl version. @ikegami

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what the error is, with tabs (are they tabs?) and changing code in the question.

However, there are many elements in the code that can be improved

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'geneIDs3_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %geneID1;

my $header = <$fh>;    
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $geneID1{ (split /\t/)[1] } = $_; 
}

say "$_ => $geneID1{$_}" for sort keys %geneID1;
```

The one "wild card" is your data; if you are unsure about `TAB` characters use `\s+` (matches tabs as well), since you only need the second field. By `split` defaults then you can do `(split)[1]`.

Comments on the original code

- Read a file ahead of time only when there is a very specific reason for that
- Declare everything, even if some special feature allows you not to (`$a`)
- Declare in smallest scope possible and close to where it's needed: `open my $fh, ...`
- Do not use special variables like `$a` except for what they are meant for!
- There is practically never a need for a C-style `for` loop. If you need indices in iteration

  ```
  foreach my $i (0 .. $#ary) { ... }
  ```

  where `$#ary` is the index of the last element of array `@ary`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I declare `$inFH1` early for readability. It's just my style. I don't know what is C-style, I just learn programming, I want to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @WenjiaZhai (1) With `open` there is no scope benefit in fact, but it is generally better to declare right where you need it.  When it's declared right under `open` there is never confusion about where it belongs. (2) "C-style" loop normally refers to `for (my $i = 0, $i < SIZE; ++$i)` -- like you do a loop in C.  Perl is a much higher-level language and offers other, more convenient ways.

Comment: @WenjiaZhai Keep learning, enjoy it :).  Find your style (but also note "good practices")

Comment: One major reason for declaring a variable ahead is that I usually countered an error `Global symbol requires explicit package name` even after I use `my`. I couldn't find the reason why I have it, but I found that if I declare variables earlier, I won't have this error.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement! I do have fun while programming. I also learn a lot from this forum.

Comment: @WenjiaZhai That means that you use the variable either outside of "_scope_" in which it is declared, or before you declare it. It is something you absolutely want to clear up. Perhaps post a question with the _exact_ code that gives you this?

Comment: @WenjiaZhai  Also ... I have to ask .. you _are_ reading some good book or a modern well-regarded tutorial while you are learning, right?

Comment: I just started my MS program in bioinformatics this fall. Yes, I've been reading some books, but in most of time, I'm reading handouts from class and do assignments.